# Differential equation - Solve relation between heat and radius in heat pipe.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

### Problem

Heat pipe's inner radius is $1$ and outer radius is $2$. It is also known that heat pipe's inner surface temperature is $100^{\circ}C$ and outer surface has temperature of $0^{\circ}C$. Define heat pipe's temperature $u=u(R)$ in function of radius $R$ when $1 \le R \le 2$. Temperature satisfies differential equation $ru''+u'=0$

---

### Attempt to solve

I drew image of the situation since we are dealing with some sort of geometry.

We are trying to figure out which function defines temperature in gray region in the image.

[image]

We know that function of temperature satisfies this condition:

$$ ru''+u'=0 $$

This means following has to be also true:

$$ u'(R)=u(R)$$
$$u''=u'$$

We can begin solving this by solving equation:

$$ ru'+u=0 $$
$$ ru'=-u $$
$$ u'=\frac{-u}{R}$$
$$ \frac{du}{dR}=-\frac{u}{R} $$
$$  \frac{\frac{du}{dR}}{u}=-\frac{1}{R} $$
$$ \frac{1}{u}\cdot \frac{du}{dR}=-\frac{1}{R} $$
Now we can integrate both sides.
$$ \int{\frac{1}{u}\cdot \frac{du}{dR}}dR=\int{-\frac{1}{R}}dR $$
$$ \int{\frac{1}{u}}du=-\frac{1}{R}dR $$
$$ \ln(u)= -\ln(R)+C $$
$$  u(R)=e^{-ln(R)+C} $$
$$  u(R)=\frac{e^{C}}{R} $$

Now we could try to solve C.

$$ \ln(u)= -\ln(R)+C $$
$$  C=\ln(u)+\ln(R) $$

Now we have two different sets of values we could solve this constant. These are

$$(1) \quad R=1,u=100^{\circ}C$$
$$(2) \quad R=2,u=0^{\circ}C$$

Computing constant:

$$ C=\ln(100)+\ln(1)\approx 4.605170186 $$
$$ C=\ln(0)+\ln(2)= \text{undefined}$$
$$ C=\lim_{n\rightarrow 0}( \ln(n)+\ln(2) )=- \infty $$
Problem is that we should be able to get same constant with both of these value sets since it's constant.

We could try to use the first constant and see if we are getting the correct solutions for the function.

$$ u(R)=\frac{e^{\ln(100)+\ln{1}}}{R} $$
$$ u(1)=\frac{e^{\ln(100)+\ln{1}}}{1}=100^{\circ}C $$
$$ u(2)=\frac{e^{\ln(100)+\ln{1}}}{2}=50^{\circ}C $$

$u(2)$ is suppose to be $0^{\circ}C$
$$  $$

Now if someone could point out where i am going wrong with this that would be highly appreciated.

### Edit:

At the beginning i was meant to say that:

$$ u'=v $$
$$ Rv'+v=0 $$

We are substituting $u'$ with $v$ and then begin to solve the equation with substitution.

Now we did end up with:

$$ v(R)=e^{-\ln{R}+C_1} $$

now we can continue solving $u(R)$.

$$ u(R)=\int{e^{-\ln{R}+C_1}} $$

Integration by substitution $u=-\ln{R}+c_1$ and $du=(-\frac{1}{R}+1)dx$.
Solving for $dx=\frac{1}{(-\frac{1}{R}+1)}du$

$$ u(R)=\int{e^u}\frac{1}{(-\frac{1}{R}+1)}du$$
since $\frac{1}{(-\frac{1}{R}+1)}$ is only constant
$$ u(R)=\frac{1}{(-\frac{1}{R}+1)}\int{e^u}du $$
$$ u(R)=\frac{1}{(-\frac{1}{R}+1)}{e^u}+c_2 $$
Now substituting $u$ backwards with $-\ln(R)+c_1$
$$ u(R)=\frac{1}{(-\frac{1}{R}+1)}e^{-\ln{R}+c_1}+c_2$$

Now i would want to solve for constant's $c_1$ and $c_2$.

We can form system of equations based on values we have.

$$ \begin{cases} \frac{1}{-\frac{1}{1}+1}e^{-\ln(1)+c_1}+c_2=100 \\ \frac{1}{-\frac{1}{2}+1}e^{-\ln(2)+c_1}+c_2=0 \end{cases} $$

Now it would be possible to solve but we get situation where we divide by zero:

$$ \frac{1}{-\frac{1}{1}+1}=\text{Undefined} $$